# split a string and enter it in textarea

Tags: java, arrays, string, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to split a string "A CV;B003 GR" and separator is (;)
and wants to enter the string in textarea of a webpage.

Format of the staring should be
(on the first line) A CV
(on the next line) B003 GR

So in this way it should be entered in text area

Please help

Comment: What do you mean by textarea of a webpage.? the HTML code ...?

Comment: Please add a screenshot of what your original input and expected out put should be ( Even if you draw it on a piece of paper. ) this will make it easier to understand what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way of doing it

```
String[] text = ("A CV;B003 GR").split(";");
String formattedText = text[0] + "\n" + text[1];
driver.findElement("YOUR_TEXTAREA_LOCATOR").sendKeys(formattedText);
```